# What does an open set in $C(X,Y)$ look like?

Tags: analysis

I'm in the metric space d where the topology generated by d is the one generated by all sets $B(x,\epsilon)$. That is $x \in X, \epsilon >0, B(x, \epsilon) = \{ y \in X |d(x,y) < \epsilon \} $

I know that $C(X,Y)$ is the set of continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$. Elements of $C(X,Y)$ look like $f:X \rightarrow Y$ such that $f$ is continuous.

I need to know what an open set of $C(X,Y)$ looks like.

Would an open set of $C(X,Y)$ be a set of open functions?

I know if a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is open, then for all $x \in X$ and for all neighborhoods $U$ of $x$, there exists neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$ such that $V \subset f(U)$.

So would an open set of $C(X,Y)$ be the set $\{ f:X \rightarrow Y | f$ is continuous and open$\}$?

Comment: There are several topologies you can consider on $C(X,Y)$. Which one are you assigned with?

Comment: $\{ f \in C(X,Y) : f > 0 \}$

Comment: So my questions also includes that X is compact and Y is the real numbers.

Comment: I'm assigned with the metric space.

Comment: No, an open set of continuous functions doesn't have to be a set of open functions.  One type of topology on C(X,Y) is generated by open balls centered at functions.  The distance between functions f and g is measured by comparing the distances between corresponding points f(x), g(x) for all x in X.  Specifically, the distance between f and g is the supremum of |f(x)-g(x)| over the set of all x in X.

Comment: If you are being asked about $C(X,Y)$ on (say) a homework assignment, then you have almost certainly been given some additional information (either in class or elsewhere in the assignment) which determines what the topology on it is.  It is impossible for us to answer unless you share that additional information with us.

Comment: In class we only deal with the metric space.  The problem also gives that X is compact, Y is the Real numbers, and Y is a Polish space.

Comment: We use the metric d where the topology generated by d is one generated by all sets $B(x, \epsilon)$

Comment: Well, what is $d$?

Comment: $d$ is just a metric.  It's defined by the usual definition of a metric (d(x,y) =0 if and only if x=y, triangle inequality, and symmetric properties hold).  The topology generated by $d$ is the one generated by all sets $B(x, \epsilon)$.  That is $x \in X, \epsilon >0, B(x, \epsilon) = \{ y \in X |d(x,y) < \epsilon \} $

Comment: Well, do you know the definition of an open set in a metric space?  You're not going to be able to get much more of a picture than that unless you specify exactly what $d$ is.

Comment: d is just a metric.  We're in a metric space.  Does that not suffice?

Comment: Eric is asking for the explicit formula for d.